# Select id and name of users having their birthday this week from database with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that stores user information in a database table. I want to output all users celeberating their birthday in each week of the year (monday - sunday), and I have this already.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
</tr>
<?php
$req = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM elementary WHERE birthday BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK" );

while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $dnn["id"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dnn["surname"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dnn["firstname"] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update your question to be more specific, i.e. which part exactly are you struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can use [WEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

```
SELECT * FROM elementary WHERE WEEK(birthday, 1) = WEEK(NOW(), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the WEEK function gave me my desired result.